# parsing XML with Apache Camel (printing null)

Tags: java, xml, apache, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have problem with parsing XML with Apache Camel. I added all necessary annotations, next I have some problems with multiple root elements then I created new class with List. Now I show my code below:

**Customer**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public @Data class Customer {

private int id;
private String name;
private String address;
private String countryCode;

@XmlElementWrapper(name="products")
@XmlElement(name="product")
private List<Product> products;
}
```

**Product**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public @Data class Product {

    private int productId;
    private String productName;
}
```

**Customers (class created because multiple root problem)**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public @Data class Customers {

@XmlElementWrapper
@XmlElement(name = "customer")
private List<Customer> customers;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Customers{" +
            "customers=" + customers +
            '}';
    }
}
```

**MyRouteBuilder**

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:/home/tkaczmarek/usr/data/inbox?noop=true")
                .bean(XmlToBean.class);
    }
}
```

**XmlToBean**

```
public class XmlToBean {
    public void transformXmlObject(Customers customers) {
        System.out.println(customers);
    }
}
```

**xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customers>
<customer>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>Tomasz Kaczmarek</name>
   <address>Łódź, ul. Błotna 5/32</address>
   <countryCode>1221</countryCode>
   <products>
      <product>
         <productId>1</productId>
         <productName>Bread</productName>
      </product>
      <product>
         <productId>2</productId>
         <productName>Meat</productName>
      </product>
   </products>
</customer>
</customers>
```

**Currently output**

```
Customers{customers=null}
```

How I can make my code working correctly? I have no idea where is a problem.

Comment: Do you have camel-jaxb on the classpath? And what version of Camel do you use? And can you better explain what is the problem, its a bit unclear

Comment: What do you mean by multiple root problem?

Answer (score -1):

Problem is solved, I deleted XmlWrapper from Customers and Customer and now it's working correctly.